# AWS Lambda not executing concurrently

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

So I defined a fairly simple AWS Lambda.  I created an HTTP GET URL for it using AWS API Gateway.  I deployed it and tested the URL in the browser and it worked.  I then created a desktop app to call the URL, it only takes one query string parameter.  I ran the code serially to call the URL 100 times with a different query string input each time, and saw that the lambda executed an average of 500 milliseconds each time.

I then changed my desktop app to issue the requests in parallel.  I expected the overall time to take maybe 1 second or so to complete, given that the longest execution time was like 950 milliseconds on average. However, when I did this, it took more than 30 seconds to complete all the requests.

I've done other tests to know the desktop app really is issuing all the URL requests in parallel, so that's not the issue.  I just don't understand why it didn't spin up 100 lambdas to service each URL request so that they executed concurrently.  It appears that the requests were buffered.

The only difference between each URL is the query string parameter.  I am, at this point, considering creating 100 different lambdas, each built with the different value previously passed in the query string, but each with a different URL so I can achieve actual concurrent execution.

Am I missing something?

Comment: There may be cold-start scale-up delays for both lambda and API gateway.  Repeat your tests multiple times?

Comment: Also, you may want to ensure that your desktop client uses *all* the possible DNS results for your endpoint hostname.  If you are latching onto a single IP address, the infrastructure may be limiting the concurrency via some unspecified mechanism, since real-world requests would not all arrive on a single IP address.   Potentially relevant info in [CloudFront docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/load-testing.html) since CloudFront always provides some front-end services to API Gateway APIs (without any configuration on your part).

Comment: So, yeah, I did see that there was a cold-start delay, and I did run them multiple times to "get around" that, but it still took a lot longer than I would expect if they were truly running concurrently.

Comment: Lambda most definitely does spin up additional containers and handle concurrent requests concurrently, so we'll have to keep troubleshooting in order to get to the bottom of what you're seeing.  Any thoughts on my prior suggestions? Logging timestamps and ensuring that all requests are not hitting your API on a single IP address?

Comment: where do you measure these figures? are these from cloudwatch logs total latency / integration latency? what operations does your lambda backend perform? in what language your desktop app is written?

Answer (score 1):

AWS lambda by default provided concurrent execution upto 75, i. e at a time 75 lambdas can be created.

EDIT: By default, AWS Lambda limits the total concurrent executions across all functions within a given region to 1000.

The previous limit was 75 per Lambdas. I didn't check the latest concurrent limit.

Here is the [Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html)

If you need more concurrency you need to raise a case with AWS team.

Comment: Could you point me to documentation about that limit?  The only limit I had seen was one that said the default concurrent execution limit was 1000.

Comment: I updated my answer. AWS Lambda limits the total concurrent executions across all functions within a given region to 1000. So probably your region already has some lambda running

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure what's up, but I will revisit my desktop code, cause I just don't see an issue with the lambda setup. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the concurrency graph of aws lambda for the function? That will show the concurrent execution. Also check the throttle metric whether the requests are getting throttle in lambda is the indiction that the concurrency limit has reached.

Comment: I cannot find a concurrency graph, so no, I didn't check it.

Answer (score -1):

Concurrent execution count will differ depending on whether or not your Lambda function is processing events from a stream-based event source.

Event sources that aren't stream-based – If you create a Lambda function to process events from event sources that aren't stream-based (for example, Amazon S3 or API Gateway), each published event is a unit of work. Therefore, the number of events (or requests) these event sources publish influences the concurrency.

You can use the following formula to estimate your concurrent Lambda function invocations:

```
events (or requests) per second * function duration
```

For example, consider a Lambda function that processes Amazon S3 events. Suppose that the Lambda function takes on average three seconds and Amazon S3 publishes 10 events per second. Then, you will have 30 concurrent executions of your Lambda function.

**Request Rate**

Request rate refers to the rate at which your Lambda function is invoked. For all services except the stream-based services, the request rate is the rate at which the event sources generate the events. For stream-based services, AWS Lambda calculates the request rate as follow:

```
request rate = number of concurrent executions / function duration
```

For example, if there are five active shards on a stream (that is, you have five Lambda functions running in parallel) and your Lambda function takes about two seconds, the request rate is 2.5 requests/second.

Source :- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html

Comment: Most of this doesn't seem relevant to the details of question.